# Reverse String at a specific Index using Recursion

Tags: java, recursion, reverse

How would I go about making it reverse the string at a specific index for example, goodbye at i=1 would be ybdoog and i=2 is bdoog. Anything before that index is just ignored in the returning string. In Java

```
public static String revStr(String s, int i) {
    if (s == null || s.length() <= 1)
        return s;
    else
        return revStr(s.substring(1), i)+ s.charAt(0);
}
```

Comment: `for example, goodbye at i=1 would be ybdoog`. - Where did `e` go?

Comment: It should be revStr, and e is gone because it should reverse the string starting at a specific index in this case 1 so it skips e when reversing.

Comment: By skips e I mean starts reversing at the specific index i.

Comment: The method returns the passed in string in reverse order starting from a specified index. i = 0 would just return the string reversed as normal.

Comment: So the result needs to have a prefix, which is not reversed. and a reversed part starting from index `i`?  Like `revStr("abcdefgh", 3) --> "abchgfed" ?`

Comment: revStr("abcdefgh", 3) would be "edcba"

Comment: It's still reversed as normal just does it on a bias.

Comment: @AlexRudenko - I'm sure it's not you who have voted to close it. The close vote is ridiculous because it's an interesting and challenging problem. AFAIK you, you can not do such a thing. I hope, the one who has done it will revert the vote after trying to solve the problem himself/herself.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash, I don't think so, I voted to close because it is actually contradicting the initial statement which is quite misleading: the result is to remove last `i` characters and reverse the remainder.

Comment: @AlexRudenko - At least I was able to understand the problem clearly after the OP responded to my comment which h[s]e did `11` minutes before your comment. No worries...it's your right...enjoy the rest of the weekend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return `s.substring(i)` instead of `s` because you want the reversed substring starting from `i`. Also, for this, the terminating condition should be `if (s == null || s.length() <= i)`.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(revStr("goodbye", 2));
        System.out.println(revStr("goodbye", 1));
        System.out.println(revStr("goodbye", 0));
    }

    public static String revStr(String s, int i) {
        if (s.length() <= i)
            return s.substring(i);
        else
            return revStr(s.substring(1), i) + s.charAt(0);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
bdoog
ybdoog
eybdoog
```

Comment: This only works with 1 should've clarified it needs to work with any i, not just one or zero for example 2 = bdoog.

Comment: @LethalLizard - Rectified the problem. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt/issue.

Comment: @ShashSinha - You are right. Thanks for pointing it out. I've updated the answer.